# While building Kivy app 'sdkmanager not installed'

Tags: python, android, user-interface, kivy, buildozer

I am building a Kivy into a Android app using buildozer and I am running into a error. When I type `buildozer -v android debug` I run into the following error.

> #sdkmanager path "/home/.../.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager" does not exist, sdkmanager is notinstalled

How can solve this problem.

Note: I am using the Windows virtual Linux terminal (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what is basically happening is that buildozer is not finding the sdk manager. There are two ways to tackle this problem. First you can download the SDK tools and unzip it in the folder. Second is to start afresh. Delete all the folders created during the build via the terminal using this command `rm -rf folder_name`. Then build the app again. This will cause the packages to be downloaded again.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the `SDK tools package` from the [downloads website](https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads). You can either download and install `Android Studio` (which should include the `sdkmanager`) or you can download the `SDK tools package` without `Android Studio` and unzip it into the the location where `buildozer` expects to find it.